# SCSS variable is not working

Tags: sass

I found myself with a problem. When I was using css I had no problem setting the properties of the html elements with css, but I'm now trying to use scss and, for some reason that I'm unaware of, I can´t change the properties using the scss variables.
I'd be thankful if anyone could give me a solution for this issue.

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**SCSS**

```
$color-1 : #202020;

#example {
    background-color: $color-1;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px; 
}
```

Comment: It works fine on CodePen. are you sure you're compiling it using command line tools?

Comment: I don't know any commands. I installed it in sublime text, so it would be highlighted. I thought that I did not have to do anything else and Chrome would be able to read it.

Comment: I don't know any commands. I just installed the package in sublime text, so it would highlight and show me any mistakes. I thought I didn't had to install anything else, and Chrome or the other browsers would be able to read the file.

Comment: Thanks. You have helped me know realize what's the issue. I had not compiled the scss to css, and it looks like it is a must. I'll try to compile it online, thanks.

Comment: Glad to be helpful!